# Is it possible to specify a different remote Git repository for each subfolder in a local repository?

Tags: git, push, pull

Here is my problem.

I have the following tree structure :

- Root

  - Common
  - CommonEntity
  - Entity

Each subfolder has subfolders. A local Git repository is initiated at the Root level.

Is it possible to specify that `Common` is linked to one remote Git repo, `CommonEntity` to another one and `Entity` to a third one, so that in one pull/push command everybody deals with its repo?

Thanks !

Comment: You could do that with submodules. Don't think so with a normal repo.

Comment: Yes you can, but it's weird. Try it with a toy repo: fork something in github, git clone it locally, go into a subdirectory and git init and see what happens at both the level of the subdirectory and the original git root. Submodules is the way to go, though: they were created for the situation you describe.

Comment: Unfortunately, git is not capable of doing this.  Remotes are global to a repository; not directory specific. Branches are pushed to remotes, and each can have upstreams defined to different remotes.  So, you can have `feature1` branch push to `remote1` and `feature2` branch push to `remote2`.  If this is not enough for what you need, you can look at the `git submodule` and `git subtree` commands. These may or may not provide the functionality you need.